# Convert 4 bytes into DWORD in C++

Tags: visual-c++, registry, timestamp, typeconverter

I have a pointer to byte, which actually points to array of 4 bytes (created by RegQueryValueEx).
I want to convert these 4 bytes into one DWORD.
Although it seems to be very simple and surely there is an existing method does it, I didn't succeed to find it.

Alternatively: The registered value is a TimeStamp. Is there a method which convert from 4-bytes array represents TimeStamp into a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into MAKEWORD MAKELONG macros.

Answer (score 6):

You're asking about how to take an array of four bytes and convert that to a 32-bit value, right? It's actually pretty simple (assuming you consider bitwise operators to be simple):

```
typedef unsigned int dword;
typedef unsigned char byte;

//Convert an array of four bytes into a 32-bit integer.
dword getDwordFromBytes(byte *b)
{
    return (b[0]) | (b[1] << 8) | (b[2] << 16) | (b[3] << 24);
}
```

This assumes your integer is stored little-endian. That means that the least significant byte is stored first, so if you had a word 0x1234, it would be stored in memory as two bytes 0x34, 0x12, in that order.

In big-endian, the number 0x1234 would be stored in memory as 0x12, 0x34. If that's what you want, then just reverse the array indexes, i.e. go from `b[3]` to `b[0]`.

**Pitfall warning:**
The following code is perfectly legal C, i.e. it will compile without errors:

```
char c[4];
int x = *((int *)c);
```

However, this works essentially by casting a `char *` to an `int *` and dereferencing it. This is considered extremely bad practice, because it introduces the following portability issues:

- Endianness, explained above. Different processor architectures store words in different ways. For example, x86 processors are little-endian, while PowerPC is big-endian. The above construct makes assumptions about how the processor interprets 4-byte values.
- Memory alignment issues.Some architectures require that word accesses be aligned. That is, the address of a multi-byte memory access must be a multiple of the word size. The above code will work on an x86, which permits unaligned accesses, but other architectures like the 68000 will choke and give a bus error.
  A variable in C is guaranteed to be properly aligned for that size; what this means is that if an `int` is 32 bits, then a compiler must guarantee alignment if the target system requires it. A `char[4]` is not guaranteed to be aligned to 4 bytes.

Comment: I knew it, and also did so. But I wonder why so simple method doesn't exist

Comment: Is there no way to point a DWORD to the same reference of the BYTE and to get the result? (with or without copying of memory)

Comment: You *can* technically say `char c[4]; int i = *((int *)c);`, but that kind of pointer trickery is usually considered bad practice, for several good reasons.

Comment: Edited the answer to elaborate on the above comment.

Comment: How about DWORD64 ? Same method would do ?

Comment: Another pitfall I forgot to mention: this answer assumes that `sizeof(int) == 4`.